# my picker item value in react native is not inserted to the database

Tags: php, react-native

I'm writing a react native form that sends data to php api for mysql database.but the picker item value is not inserted correctly and when i remove it from query and it gets 0 as default in db , informations are inserted.
 i changed the database structure for it from int to varchar but didn't work.
here is my react native code:

```
import React,{Component}  from 'react';
import {TextInput,Picker}from 'react-native';
import {View ,Button,Text,Input} from 'native-base';
import Axios from 'axios';

export default class Reserve extends Component{

constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.state={
        dateSelection:'',
        timeSelection:'',
        tableSelection:'',
        numOfTables:''
    }
}


reserve = () =>{
    Axios.post('http://192.168.251.2/restaurant/reserve.php', 
            {date:this.state.dateSelection,
            time:this.state.timeSelection,
            table:this.state.tableSelection,
            numOfTables:this.state.numOfTables} );

}

render() {
    return (
        //need to add style
        <View style={{}}>

            <TextInput  
            placeholder="Enter date with this format: year/month/day" 
            style={{width:200,margin:10 }}
            onChangeText= {dateSelection => this.setState({dateSelection})}
            />

            <TextInput  
            placeholder="Enter time" 
            style={{width:200,margin:10 }}
            onChangeText= {timeSelection => this.setState({timeSelection})}

            />

            <Text>table</Text>
            <Picker
            style={{width:'80%'}}
        selectedValue={this.state.tableSelection}
        onValueChange={(itemValue,itemIndex) => this.setState({tableSelection : itemValue})}>


                <Picker.Item label="choose some thing!!" value=""/>
                <Picker.Item label="1-2" value="2" />
                <Picker.Item label="3-5" value="5"/>
                <Picker.Item label="6-8" value="8"/>
                <Picker.Item label="more" value="12"/>
            </Picker>

            <TextInput  
            placeholder="number of tables" 
            style={{width:200,margin:10 }}
            onChangeText= {numOfTables => this.setState({numOfTables})}

            />
            <Button  onPress={()=>this.reserve()}>
            <Text>reserve</Text>
            </Button>
        </View>
    );
}
```

}
 and this is my php code:

```
<?php
$serverName="localhost";
$userName="root";
$password="";
$dbnaame="restaurant_reservation";

$conn=new mysqli($serverName,$userName,$password,$dbnaame);
 if($conn->connect_error){
die("connection failes".$conn->connect_error);

 }
 mysqli_set_charset($conn,"utf8");


 $json=file_get_contents("php://input");
 $json = json_decode($json, true);
 $date= $json['date'];
 $time=$json['time'];
 $table = $json['table'];
 $numOfTables = $json['numOfTables'];


$insetQuery="INSERT INTO reservation (date,time,table,numOfTables) 
 VALUES('$date','$time','$table','$numOfTables')";
if($conn->query($insetQuery)){
    $data="table reserved successfully" ;
}
else{
    $data="reservation error" ;
}

echo $data;
$conn->close();
 ?>
```

Comment: Have you tried hard coding a value for the tableSelection? Does that insert into the database as expected?

Comment: I created a snack (https://snack.expo.io/SyUXCrPXV) that does fundamentally what you are doing in the app, without the api request, it just displays what has been stored in state when the button is pressed, the picker value updates as expected.